# Updating HERE maps with traffictiles with leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, http, maps, leaflet, here-api

We have HERE maps working with leaflet.js. Our app used OpenStreetmap before and we wanted to try out a new map provider, specifically one with traffic flow information.

We have the evaluation API keys, we modified our code to create the right http request and it was remarkably easy to get HERE maps working instead of OSM.

The HELP website seems to indicate that StackOverflow is the preferred support mechanism.

Our question is not technical, our app seems to work very well with HERE maps, it only took 90 mins to convert our app to use HERE maps, but how often do we need to refresh the map to update the traffic flow tile information?

Before we had traffic flow information, it made no difference if a user didn't update the map as it was unlikely that a new road would be built in the next 30 mins around them, however traffic information is volatile, traffic information from 30 mins ago is not much use, people want the latest updates.

So how fast should we refresh the map tiles? Once every five mins, ten minutes? The downside to this is that we then eat into our transaction limits. Should we be looking for HTTP 304 type responses? Does a 304 response eat into our transaction limits?

Is there an other way to do this? Any advice on good practise welcomed.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The HERE traffic tiles are valid between 1 to 5 Minutes (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/tile-traffic.html).

I strongly believe that the request is counted against your transactions no matter what the response. So it's up to you how fresh you want afford the traffic data to be for your clients. The link above states explicitly that you should not cache traffic tiles because of the tile limited validity but in the end it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I now recall reading this before but it must have been pushed into long term memory (/dev/null) :)

We'll experiment with the transaction count, and see what it looks like and report back. I would have hoped a 304 would have meant that no transaction would be counted. We have experimented further with the tiles and they all report 60 secs for caching. Doing a subsequent transaction it appears to show the tile eTag is updated after 60 secs regardless of whether the traffic has changed.

Comment: We'll do more tests and report back as I think this may be something of use to other people.